# wordpress - frontend post form issue

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation

I have a post form on front end where users can post (`post_type = product`) from the form. As a part of it I have tried implementing few server side validations as in below code. The issue is that the validations are all working fine but the data is getting saved on form submission even when the validation fails.
Ideally the form submission should fail when there is a field validation failure.
I am not sure if `$hasError = true` is working or not, there might be a very simple logic I am missing which I am not getting. Any help regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$postTitleError = '';

    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

        if (trim($_POST['postTitle']) === '') {
            $postTitleError = 'msg 1';
            $hasError = true;
        }
        if (trim($_POST['postCat1']) === '') {
            $postTitleError = 'msg2';
            $hasError = true;
        }
        if (trim($_POST['postPrice']) === '') {
            $postTitleError = 'msg3';
            $hasError = true;
        }
        if (trim($_POST['postTime']) === '') {
            $postTitleError = 'msg4';
            $hasError = true;
        }
        if (trim($_POST['postTimeMin']) === '') {
            $postTitleError = 'msg5';
            $hasError = true;
        }
        if (trim($_POST['postContent']) === '') {
            $postTitleError = 'msg6';
            $hasError = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        //$postTitleError = '';
        $resultArr = array();
        $error_msg = false;

    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

        if (isset($_POST['postTitle'])  && !empty($_POST["postTitle"])) {
            //$postTitleError = 'msg 1';
            //$hasError = true;
            $postTitle=$_POST['postTitle'];

        }
        else
        {
            $resultArr['status'] = 'failure';
            $resultArr['error_msg_postTitle']= "msg 1";
            $error_msg = true;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['postCat1']) && !empty($_POST["postCat1"]) ) {
           // $postTitleError = 'msg2';
           // $hasError = true;
           $postCat1=$_POST['postCat1'];
        }
        else
        {
            $resultArr['status'] = 'failure';
            $resultArr['error_msg_postCat1']= "msg2";
            $error_msg = true;
        }


        if (isset($_POST['postPrice']) && !empty($_POST["postPrice"]) ) {
           // $postTitleError = 'msg3';
            //$hasError = true;
            $postPrice=$_POST['postPrice'];
        }
        else
        {
            $resultArr['status'] = 'failure';
            $resultArr['error_msg_postPrice']= "msg3";
            $error_msg = true;
        }


        if (isset($_POST['postTime']) && !empty($_POST["postTime"]) ) {
            //$postTitleError = 'msg4';
            //$hasError = true;
            $postTime=$_POST['postTime'];
        }
        else
        {
            $resultArr['status'] = 'failure';
            $resultArr['error_msg_postTime']= "msg4";
            $error_msg = true;
        }


        if (isset($_POST['postTimeMin']) && !empty($_POST["postTimeMin"]) ) {
           // $postTitleError = 'msg5';
           // $hasError = true;
           $postTimeMin=$_POST['postTimeMin'];
        }
        else
        {
            $resultArr['status'] = 'failure';
            $resultArr['error_msg_postTimeMin']= "msg5";
            $error_msg = true;
        }


        if (isset($_POST['postContent']) && !empty($_POST["postContent"]) ) {
            //$postTitleError = 'msg6';
           // $hasError = true;
           $postContent=$_POST['postContent'];
        }
        else
        {
            $resultArr['status'] = 'failure';
            $resultArr['error_msg_postContent']= "msg6";
            $error_msg = true;
        }

        if($error_msg == false)
        {
            //here publish post code 
        }
        else
        {

            //here Error message prine
        }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Maulik patel. I made few changes in the code and implemented, it worked like charm and I understood where was the mistake.